# I need help about the nohup command using Java

Tags: java, linux, bash, nohup

I'm a beginning Linux developer.
I have a 2 part question about "`nohup`".

I programmed an ssh session using Java.

```
 String serverIP = "xxx.xxx.xxx";
 connection = new Connection(serverIP);
 Session session  = connection.openSession();
 String command = "nohup java -jar <xx.jar>";
 session.execute(command);
 ...
```

I typed        `ps -ef | grep xx.jar`in the Linux terminal(CentOS)

After that , the terminal returned

```
root 2000 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7 bash -c nohup java -jar <xx.jar>

root 2001 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7 java -jar <xx.jar>
```

and did not return the `nohup.out` file.

But, when I typed the nohup command and 'ps -ef' directly in the terminal,

it returned

```
 root 2001 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7 java -jar <xx.jar>
```

and did return the `nohup.out` file in the current directory.

My 2 part question is:

1. **why did the terminal make the `bash -c nohup java -jar <xx.jar>` process
2. and why did it not return the `nohup.out` file.